# Positive / Negative semi-definite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible for a matrix in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to be both positive and negative semi-definite without it being the zero-matrix? My intuition suggests no, but I am finding it very hard to prove otherwise. Conversely, in trying to find such a matrix, no theorems really exist to generate one.

Comment: What definitions are you working with?

Comment: only the definition of a positive / negative semi-definite matrix. I have also the quadratic form: Q(v) = v*Av for some matrix A, where v is a vector of length n from the complex vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is PSD, then $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$. On the other hand, if it is NSD, then $\langle Ax,x \rangle \leq 0$ for all $x$.

Overall, $\langle Ax,x \rangle =0$ for all $x$. Since $A$ is self adjoint (this is either part of the definition/a consequence of being positive/negative definite depending on your definition), you can conclude that $A=0$.

Comment: If A = A* and v*Av = 0, i unfortunately still really dont see how that implies then that A = 0.

Comment: @MichaelMao See for instance:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312388/relation-between-t-0-and-tx-x-0/312397
This is a general property of Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @MichaelMao Use Polarization Identity for $ \langle Ax, y \rangle$ to see that $ \langle Ax, y \rangle=0$ for all $x,y$ Then put $y=Ax$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity