# Proof that $\langle x , T(x) \rangle = 0$ implies $T(x) = 0$ for a vector space over a complex field.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, inner-products

I know that this has a proof at [Relation between $T=0$ and $(Tx,x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312388/relation-between-t-0-and-tx-x-0) (and some other questions) but my question is specifically about how to prove this by *contradiction* rather than directly. (I thought it would be easier this way, but I'm really struggling to come up with a proof).

The exact statement I'm trying to prove is this: let $V$ be a vector space, and $T : V \to V$ a linear transformation. Assume that thist vector space is over the field $\mathbb{C}$, then prove that if $\forall x\Big(\langle x, T(x)\rangle = 0 \Big)$, then $T = 0$.

I started like this

- Assume that the statement is false, then it must be that $\langle x, T(x) \rangle = 0$ and $T \ne T_0$.
- Therefore, there exists $a, b \in V$ such that $b = T(a)$ and $a \ne 0$ and $b \ne 0$. By assumption we have that $\langle a, b \rangle = 0$. From here I think I should try to show that
  $b=0$, and the fact that this is over a complex field  must be important (as the statement is false if we are working over a real field). Unfortunately I got really stuck here. I thought about trying to express $a$ in terms of something like $x + iy$ (for some vectors $x, y$ both with real coordinates) and then to write $b = T(x + iy)$, so that we have

$$
\begin{align}
\langle x + iy, T(x  + iy) \rangle
&= \langle x, T(x) \rangle  + \overline{i} \langle x, T(y) \rangle + i \langle y, T(x) \rangle + i \overline{i} \langle y, T(y) \rangle \\
&= 0  + \overline{i} \langle x, T(y) \rangle + i \langle y, T(x) \rangle + 0 \\
&= i\left(- \langle x, T(y) \rangle + \langle y, T(x) \rangle \right)
\end{align}
$$

- And this must be equal to zero, therefore $- \langle x, T(y) \rangle + \langle y, T(x) \rangle = 0$, that is $\langle x, T(y)  \rangle = \langle y, T(x) \rangle$ but I have no idea what to do with this.

Any help would be much appreciated (sorry for the mess).

Comment: The title is missing $=0$?

Comment: What does $(a,b)\in T$ mean? Do you mean, vectors $a$ and $b$ such that $T(a)=b$? Not the most felicitous notation, given that ordered pairs often show up in linear algebra playing other roles.

Comment: Yes, because functions are sets of ordered pairs. Sorry, it's not good notation.

Comment: Then perhaps just write "there exist nonzero vectors $a$ and $b$ with $T(a)=b$ and $\langle a,b\rangle = 0$"...

Comment: You should specify that $x$ and $y$ are vectors with **real** coordinates, as that makes them uniquely determined by $a$ and $b$.

Comment: You aren't really doing a proof by contradiction. You are doing a "fake proof by contradiction". You are assuming $b\neq 0$; but you are trying to do a direct computation from which you will deduce that $b=0$, *without every using the fact that $b\neq 0$*. This is just a direct proof with the line "assume $b\neq 0$" added at the top, and the line "which contradicts our assumption that $b\neq 0$" at the bottom. It isn't really a proof by contradiction, even though it is presented as such.

Comment: Thanks Ted Shifrin and Arturo Magidin, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is good, but contradiction is not necessary.

I usually have inner products semilinear in the first variable and linear in the second one, fix the argument for your convention, if needed.

First we “polarize”: since $\langle x+y,T(x+y)\rangle=0$ for every $x,y\in V$, we can expand and obtain
$$
\langle x,T(y)\rangle+\langle y,T(x)\rangle=0
$$
(write down the steps). This holds for every $x$ and every $y$, so it remains valid when we replace $x$ by $ix$ and we obtain
$$
-i\langle x,T(y)\rangle+i\langle y,T(x)\rangle=0
$$
Removing the factor $i$ and summing the two relations, we obtain
$$
2\langle y,T(x)\rangle=0
$$
for every $x,y\in V$. Now you should be able to finish.

Comment: Thanks! We just set $y = T(x)$, from which it follows that $T(x) = 0$ right? If you don't mind me asking how did you think to first consider $x + y$ and then relate this to $v$, rather than starting with $v$ and then trying to manipulate the specific $v$ - is it just a standard technique?

Comment: @peritremic Yes, it's a standard technique when you have a “quadratic form” like $x\mapsto \langle x,T(x)$. Well this is not really a quadratic form, but it works…